# Stored procedure causing the error "Exceeded limit rates: too many table update operations for this table" in BQ SQL despite no "update" statements

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have an SQL query that contains a stored procedure that needs to be called many times. This is to repeatedly write to the same table row by row. However, when this is done in BQ, it throws this error:

> Exceeded limit rates: too many table update operations for this table

This is what the code looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE mydataset.my_procedure()
BEGIN
    CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE myproject.mydataset.results_table AS
    WITH cte_statement AS (
        SELECT 
        col1, col2,...
        LAG(col1) OVER (PARTITION BY t ORDER BY d) AS val1,
        LAG(col2) OVER (PARTITION BY t ORDER BY d) AS val2
        FROM myproject.mydataset.sourcetable
        ORDER BY col2
    )
    SELECT col1, col2, ...
    CASE WHEN val1...
    CASE WHEN val2...
    FROM cte_statement
    ORDER BY col1;
END;

CALL mydataset.my_procedure();
CALL mydataset.my_procedure();
CALL mydataset.my_procedure();
...
CALL mydataset.my_procedure();
CALL mydataset.my_procedure();
CALL mydataset.my_procedure();
```

I tried removing the CTE and replacing it with an intermittent table and got the same error. Presumably this is caused by the CREATE/REPLACE TABLE statement but I'm not sure how to work around this.

Comment: Your `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE` statement is really an `INSERT` in disguise, which is still DML, which in way, is just like an `UPDATE` statement (as, depending on the engine, an `UPDATE` is often a `DELETE+INSERT`).

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I may suggest is to change the script in such a way to space out individual table updates. I.e. you can update one column from table 1, then another column from table 2,.., so on, then go back to update the second column in table 1.
This quota is per table, so as long as there are less than 5 operations per 10 seconds for a single table,
There won't be any quota's issue.
**You can see this public doc for more information.**
[Document1](https://cloud.google.com/knowledge/kb/exceeded-rate-limits-too-many-table-update-operations-when-running-load-jobs-in-bigquery-000004366) & [Document2](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/troubleshoot-quotas)